# How expensive are IEEE 754 double operations in respect to each other on Intel I7 chips?

Tags: x86, double, bit-manipulation, intel, ieee

I want an estimative of, for example, how much more expensive is a division in relation to addition, with IEEE 754 doubles on intel processors. I need that in order to estimate which operations could lead to faster performance in an specific inner loop.

Comment: http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort, plus it's got nothing to do with the `c` or `c++` tags....

Comment: Why is bit-manipulation involved?

Answer (score 4):

From the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html), pages 14-14 and 14-15,

- `ADDSD` has a latency of 5 cycles and a throughput of 1/cycle.
- `DIVSD` has a latency of 62 cycles and a throughput of 1/61 cycles.

So, if your code has tough data dependency problems, addition is about 12 times faster than division.  With careful optimization, however, you can make addition 61 times faster than division.  Other factors will probably make the gap larger.

Comment: Most notably, unless you're writing assembly, you can only guess which instructions your compiler is generating.

Comment: Or you can just look at what assembly is generated (no guessing); which IMO is a pretty good way to write assembly (write source and monitor the compiler output). Compilers write amazing assembly most of the time, but sometimes they need a code review from a human.